# Filter out JSON data using JQ based on dates

Tags: json, jq

JSON Data

```
{
  "DateTime": "2022-12-09T16:00:00.000Z",
  "Name": "name1"
}
{
  "DateTime": "2023-12-09T16:00:00.000Z",
  "Name": "name2"
}
{
  "DateTime": "2028-12-09T16:00:00.000Z",
  "Name": "name3"
}
{
  "DateTime": "2030-12-09T16:00:00.000Z",
  "Name": "name4"
}
```

Required result: Need to filter only those rows which is between year 2022 and 2030

Required output

```
{
  "DateTime": "2023-12-09T16:00:00.000Z",
  "Name": "name2"
}
{
  "DateTime": "2028-12-09T16:00:00.000Z",
  "Name": "name3"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A simple solution** could be to get the first `4` chars from your `DateTime`, convert that [`tonumber`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#tonumber) and use that as your `$year`

Then [`select()`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#select(boolean_expression)) all those where `$year > 2022 and $year < 2030`:

```
map((.DateTime[0:4] | tonumber) as $year | select($year > 2022 and $year < 2030))
```

##### [Try it online](https://jqplay.org/s/wujHZRgAXDa)

---

**A more complex solution**, where we *correctly* parse the date:

```
map(.DateTime | (sub("(?<time>.*)\\.[\\d]{3}(?<tz>.*)"; "\(.time)\(.tz)") | fromdateiso8601 |  strftime("%Y") | tonumber) as $year | select($year > 2022 and $year < 2030))
```

This uses the [`sub`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#sub(regex;tostring)sub(regex;string;flags)) from this [Github Issue](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/1409) to remove the milliseconds part of your date so [`fromdateiso8601`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Dates) understands it and we can use [`strftime`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Dates) to format it to a year

##### [Try it online](https://jqplay.org/s/as4Wv01yc3G)

---

Output

```json
[
  {
    "DateTime": "2023-12-09T16:00:00.000Z",
    "Name": "name2"
  },
  {
    "DateTime": "2028-12-09T16:00:00.000Z",
    "Name": "name3"
  }
]
```

Comment: The input is a stream of objects, and so is the "required output". Both of the approaches given here could be simplified by omitting the `--slurp` option (which is implied in the response, and explicitly set in the jqplay demos), and just using the filters without the surrounding `map`, i.e. just `jq '(.DateTime[0:4] | tonumber) as $year | select($year > 2022 and $year < 2030)' file.json` in the first case for example.